# Search entire worksheet for a cell contain a string of text (formula)

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have an Excel file which has a Summary tab at the start, followed by several tabs which contain weekly information. As the weeks progress, I may add additional rows to the weekly sheet, meaning that the total is not always in the same cell on each sheet.

I am looking for a formula that will search a specified weekly sheet for the words "Grand Total" and return it's address, which I can then build into other formulas, so that the Summary sheet will populate the correct values regardless of whether additional rows have been added.

Answer (score 0):

*Hi, your question should always contain your current efforts and ideally some code as well. But given it's a fairly basic question to answer and you're new here I decided to answer it*

---

With that aside...:

```
Option Explicit
Private Function get_total () As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Your Sheet Name") 'set your own
    Dim lc as Long
    lc = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' determines last column with data

    'some other useful variables
    Dim lr as Long 'last row
    Dim temp as Range 'find result
    Dim i as Long ' loop index

    For i = 1 to lc
       lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
       Set temp = ws.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lr, i)).Find("Grand Total", lookin:=xlValues)
       If Not temp Is Nothing Then 'if we found grand total, return it
            Set get_total = temp 'return range of result
       End If
     Next i

   Exit Function 'if no Range found, exit function ("return;")

End Function
```

---

**Technically, that alone is the answer, but for practical use, you might want to visualize it**

So with this function you will loop through all the columns and it will stop upon Grand Total is found, or alternatively will "`return`" void if not found any

Obviously, this only is a function, so if you wanted to print out the result, you could create a procedure like this:

```
Private Sub print_grand_total() 
  Dim res as Range
  Set res = get_total
  If Not res Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox("Found in Cell[" & res.row & "," & res.Column & "]")
  Else
     MsgBox("Grand Total not found!")
  End If
End Sub
```

So, I've set an example sheet:

[image]

After running the procedure, it returns the result, successfully:

[image]

> **Note:** *Small implementation foresight: This will not work in cases, where the first row is empty (because it can't detect last column properly then). Edit the `lc` code depending on where your data range begins*